# Unable to set a watchpoint in either gdb or lldb

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, debugging, gdb, lldb

I am trying to set a watchpoint while debugging my app on the device. I am unable to set it on either gdb or lldb.

On lldb, I don't see the `watchpoint set` option in the debugger even though [this page](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) mentioned that it exists. When I try to run `watchpoint set`, lldb tells me that the command is not valid.

On gdb, I do get to set the watchpoint (using `watch var`), but when I try to continue execution I get this:

```
Can't set hardware watchpoints without the 'Z2' (write-watchpoint) packet.
```

I see no further output in the gdb window nor do I think I can interact with it. The app also remains hung at this point.

I am using Xcode 4.3.2 (4E2002) on OS X Lion. I tried setting the watchpoint on devices with iOS 5.1 and iOS 5.0.1 but encounter the same problem on both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before Xcode 4.5, watchpoints were not supported for iOS development with either lldb or gdb.

With Xcode 4.5, they are supported for iOS and Mac OS X debugging with lldb.

In Xcode, in the locals window, you can right-click/control-click on a variable and there will be an option to set a watchpoint on it.  From the debugger console, to add a watchpoint on a variable called foo, you can do

```
(lldb) watchpoint set variable foo
```

the shortest unambiguous command is always valid in lldb so this would do the same thing,

```
(lldb) w s v foo
```

The current x86 and arm cpus only support 4 watchpoints being set simultaneously.

Comment: That is awesome. Once I have upgraded to Xcode 4.5 and verified this, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGupta You forgot to accept his answer. But this works for me! :D

Comment: I notice that watchpoints don't work too well with pointer variables, and with multi-threaded environment. Is this the case?

Comment: I'm getting nothing but EXC_BREAKPOINT code=EXC_DA_ARM_DEBUG, and I can't continue after it happens. No info prints out in the lldb console when it happens, either.

Answer (score 0):

I read this somewhere in the Apple Dev Forums : 
 "The set command exists in the trunk version but not in the Xcode version yet."

I am also stuck with this problem where I want to keep a watch on a variable and see where its value changes...